# One To Many associate

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model `Shop` and a model `Comment`.

on the `Comment` model:

```
public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop', 'commentable_id');
    }
```

The `Shop` model is:

```
public function comments() {       
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'commentable_id');
    }
```

So the relationship is One To Many

I want to copy all the comments of a `Shop` and attach them to another `Shop`:

```
$shop = Shop::find(1);
$comments = $shop->comments()->pluck('id')->toArray(); // it works, i have all the ids of the comments

$othershop = Shop::find(2);
$othershop->comments()->associate($comments); // doesn't work
$othershop->comments()->attach($comments); // doesn't work
```

Anyone knows how to proceed with a One to Many situation?

Comment: try `$othershop->comments()->saveMany($shop->comments);`

Comment: Maybe with ->sync ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @Ruub `sync` establishes relation with existing rows. He needs to create copies of those comments first. @rkj answer is correct, since `saveMany` will basically iterate through all comments and call `save` for `comments()` relation (which will insert new instance of comment)

Comment: Ah, you are right sir :)

Comment: @rkj That would do if I wanted to update the comments but in this case I'm searching for an efficient way to duplicate.

Comment: what does duplicate do ? it create new record. Just give it a try. check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: @rkj It seems that `saveMany` will not duplicate the comments in the DB. It will update the current comments and update the `commentable_id` (or in simpler cases the `shop_id`) to the `$othershop->id`

Comment: no, it will create new record for each comments in collection. did you try ?

Comment: @rkj yup I tried and it updated instead of creating a new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `createMany` method of relationship:

```php
$othershop->comments()->createMany($shop->comments->toArray());
```

You can also utilize chunking if one shop can have many comments (split it into more queries to make it more memory efficient):

```php
$shop->comments()->chunk(500, function ($comments) use ($othershop) {
    $othershop->comments()->createMany($comments->toArray());
});
```

**edit:** changed my answer based on comments.

Comment: In a one-to-many relationship, that's also not copying the comments... [see source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L240-L266)

Comment: @d3jn Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Just another thing, it's not duplicating the other field like `user_id` in the `comments` table, any hint on this ?

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment, it has nothing to do with the answer, I forgot to change the `$fillable` of my `Comment` model.

Answer (score 0):

To copy comments, you first need to replicate them. Then you can associate them with their owning model:

```
$shop = Shop::find(1);
$otherShop = Shop::find(2);

$comments = $shop->comments()->get();
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $tmp = $comment->replicate();
    $tmp->shop()->associate($otherShop);
    $tmp->save();
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working but I think @d3jn solution is more efficient